# How to create an HTML checkbox with a clickable label and clickable box without the clickable "whitespace"

Tags: html, css

I was working through a W3 school tutorial and I can't figure out how to make the white space right of the text to not "check" the checkbox when clicked (for a similar program I am working on). I only want the checkbox to be activated when either the box or text is clicked on.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `width: 25px;` to the container's style. The width should be just large enough to cover every checkbox (see snippet below):

```css
/* Stylesheet */
/* The container */

.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  width: 25px; /* this was added to fix the issue */
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the checkmark/indicator */

.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>Custom Checkboxes</h1>

  <label class="container">One
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label class="container">Two
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

  <label class="container">Three
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>

</body>

</html>
```

After applying this fix, if you hover over each item with the mouse you will see that the hand icon changes to an arrow as soon as you leave the checkbox + text area.

Answer (score 0):

change the css of .container. padding-left from 35px to 25 px. It will remove white space.

```
.container {
display: block;
position: relative;
padding-left: 25px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 22px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

}

Comment: The simples solution would be to deploy a checkbox WITHOUT label followed by a label, and set the event of the level to set/clear the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ul, li

Use li to display line by line
then have your labels wrapped inside.

Making label(.container) to display as "inline-block" will help to take auto width

```
.container {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Remove list styles on li's

```
li {
 list-style: none;
}
```

Refer: https://codepen.io/sprushika/pen/oqReEO